# Replace eregi_replace with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I convert this function with this parameters

```
eregi_replace('<[^>]*>', '', $stringToDisplay)
```

to preg_replace?

Answer (score 4):

The [PCRE regular expressions](http://php.net/book.pcre) require [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) that separate the pattern from [optional modifiers](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) (in this case `i` to reflect a case insensitive match):

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/i', '', $stringToDisplay)
```

But since there are not letters that need to be interpreted without case, you can omit the `i` modifier.

And if you happen to try parsing HTML or a similar markup language with regular expressions, consider using a proper parser.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_replace('/\<[^>]*\>/i', '', $stringToDisplay)
```

More details - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php